# How to config Apache to get Symfony4 routes working in subdirectory on a WordPress domain

Tags: wordpress, apache, symfony, symfony4

On my Apache server I have a WordPress installation working on www.domain.com and I want to add a Symfony4 installation on www.domain.com/symfony. Symfony routes are taken to the WordPress 404 page (but still are the correct URL i.e. www.domain.com/symfony/about). However, if there are NO routes defined in my Symfony app, then the base www.domain.com/symfony/ URL will correctly display the Symfony4 getting started page. What is wrong in my Apache conf files?

Web server is Apache 2.4, I have tried using Alias and AliasMatch directives in the /etc/apache2 conf files. Alias displays WordPress 404 for all Symfony routes and AliasMatch appends many /index.php's onto the URL and displays the same 404. I tried to copy what phpmyadmin does with its `Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin`

```
# /etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.conf
<Directory /var/www/wordpress>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    ServerAdmin me@myemail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
</VirtualHost>


# /var/www/wordpress/.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>


# /etc/apache2/sites-available/symfony.conf
Alias /symfony /var/www/symfony/app/public
<Directory /var/www/symfony/app/public>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from All
    FallbackResource /index.php
</Directory>


# /var/www/symfony/app/config/routes.yaml
about_index:
  path: /about
  controller: App\Controller\AboutController::index
```

I expected `www.domain.com/symfony/about` to go to `/var/www/symfony/app/public/index.php` and route to `App\Controller\AboutController::index`, but it looks like WordPress is trying to find the page `/symfony/about` and 404's.

When I change my `Alias /symfony /var/www/symfony/app/public` to `AliasMatch ^/symfony.* /var/www/symfony/app/public` it changes the Symfony URL to  `www.domain.com/symfony/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php` but has the same result (WordPress 404 page). None of my changes have impacted the WordPress part at all - it still functions perfectly.

## EDIT 1

Tried a new conf to test if it's my symfony config - it works as expected so I just think it must be something in my Apache confs. This config treats the symfony app as the main site and wordpress is totally disabled:

```
# /etc/apache2/sites-available/symfony_only.conf
<Directory /var/www/symfony/app/public>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from All

    FallbackResource /index.php
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/symfony/app/public/bundles>
    FallbackResource disabled
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    ServerAdmin me@myemail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/symfony/app/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I think the problem could be that the wordpress route matches first and due its rewrite rule it will also take responsibility for the symfony routes. Have you tried moving the contents from your symfony.conf into the `<VirtualHost>`-definition before the line with `DocumentRoot ...`?

Comment: I have edited the wordpress.conf file to put the symfony.conf in the vhost block between the admin email and the document root line, but it has the same behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I got a working conf now. Not sure if it's even resulting in any different configuration than the one I had. I also did a lot of `php bin/console cache:clear` as I was even getting 404 and 500 errors on the little debug bar at the bottom of the symfony welcome page (not displayed on the bar, but the bar actually wouldn't properly load). The below file is my entire conf which I combined into one file. It serves from my Symfony4 app if the url path begins with `/symfony`, and the routes all work.

```
# /etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress_symfony.conf
Alias /symfony /var/www/symfony/app/public

<Directory /var/www/symfony/app/public>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from All
    FallbackResource /index.php
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/symfony/app/public/bundles>
    FallbackResource disabled
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/wordpress>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    ServerAdmin me@myemail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Also I added the symfony/apache-pack with composer which added this .htaccess in the symfony public directory. The docs said I can get improved performance by moving all these rules into my .conf file and disabling overrides:

```
# /var/www/symfony/app/public/.htaccess
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```